# Mysql Left Join And Merge Column

Tags: mysql

```
+----------------------+
| post_id | message    |
+----------------------+
| 1       | message 1  |
+----------------------+
| 2       | message 2  |
+----------------------+

+----------+---------+-------------------------+
| reply_id | post_id |message                  |
+----------+---------+-------------------------+
|    1     |    1    |  reply 1 to message 1   |
+----------+---------+-------------------------+
|    2     |    1    |  reply 2 to message 1   |
+----------+---------+-------------------------+
|    3     |    1    |  reply 3 to message 1   |
+----------+---------+-------------------------+
|    4     |    2    |  reply 1 to message 2   |
+----------+---------+-------------------------+
```

I got this two table name `post` and `post_replies`
the `post_id` in table `post_replies` is Fk to Pk in table `post`
What i want to do is find post message and it replies as one column only

if i were run something like this:

```
SELECT p.message, pr.message FROM `posts` AS p LEFT JOIN post_replies AS pr ON p.post_id = pr.post_id
```

it will return something like this

```
+-----------+-------------------------+
| message   |   message               |
+-----------+-------------------------+
| message 1 |  reply 1 to message 1   |
+-----------+-------------------------+
| message 1 |  reply 2 to message 1   |
+-----------+-------------------------+
| message 1 |  reply 3 to message 1   |
+-----------+-------------------------+
| message 2 |  reply 1 to message 2   |
+-----------+-------------------------+
```

Is there a way i can get **Result** like this:

```
+-------------------------+
|   message               |
+-------------------------+
|   message 1             |
+-------------------------+
|  reply 1 to message 1   |
+-------------------------+
|  reply 2 to message 1   |
+-------------------------+
|  reply 3 to message 1   |
+-------------------------+
|   message 2             |
+-------------------------+
|  reply 1 to message 2   |
+-------------------------+
```

If i run

```
SELECT p.message FROM `posts` AS p LEFT JOIN post_replies AS pr ON p.id = pr.post_id
```

this will return message from `post` table

Or

```
SELECT pr.message FROM `posts` AS p LEFT JOIN post_replies AS pr ON p.id = pr.post_id
```

this will return message from table `post_replies` only

Is it possible anyway?

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: The real important question is why you would want to do this? Are you trying to 'automatically' create a table header?

Comment: @Perception sort off..i want to loop through the result and put in table..if result in multiple column, i have a problem to echo out the result cause it might produce duplicate..anyway is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UNION the two queries you provided and introduce the right ordering:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT p.id, 0 x, p.message
  FROM posts AS p
  LEFT JOIN post_replies AS pr ON p.id = pr.post_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT p.id, pr.id, pr.message
  FROM posts AS p
  LEFT JOIN post_replies AS pr ON p.id = pr.post_id
) x
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

If you don't want duplicates, change "UNION ALL" to just "UNION".

Comment: this will return duplicate message from table `posts`.ok distince remove duplicate data..but u see..if i have more than one message in table post, it will return all message from table post than from table reply..is it possible to get message from table post and all it replies first then returning other message from table post and it replies..

Comment: This gives him all the messages, then all the replies to the messages. In one column. With the associations between the messages and replies broken! I can't believe this is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @slier it wasn't clear whether he wants or doesn't want duplicates, however I have added a remark regarding alternatives for both.

Comment: @Perception long ago I stopped wondering why people want mental things and I now stick to answering the question as asked. I don't understand why he would want this either.

Comment: @Bohemian, I dont blame you, I do the same thing! I think the OP is trying to chain a message and its replies together, effectively converting row data into columnar data. So that a 'message' is grouped together with its replies, and each message + replies is in a separate column of the result set returned.

Comment: @Bohemian check edited post, is there a ways i can get `result` i want?

Comment: Ah, thats why I shouldn't be trying to read peoples minds! He wants the data all in one column!

Comment: what is " 0 x " syntax meaning ? @Bohemian

Comment: @Domezchoc “0 x” is the value 0 with the column name “x”. It’s called as *alias*, often coded as “0 as x”, but the “as” keyword is optional. With unions, the names of the columns are taken from the first subquery.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not want you want, but just posting if this solves your problem

$query

```
SELECT 
    group_concat(pr.message SEPARATOR '|'), p.message,  
FROM 
    `posts` AS p 
LEFT JOIN 
    post_replies AS pr ON p.post_id = pr.post_id 
GROUP BY
    pr.post_id


+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| message   |   message                                                                  |
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| message 1 |  reply 1 to message 1 | reply 2 to message 1  | reply 3 to message 1       |
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```